# TypeScript - Why are global exported variables undefined in some contexts when they were set in another context?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, scoping

I'm trying to have a shared store of global variables in a Vue.js application. Since only some properties are relevant to the state of the actual application, only those are wrapped in a Vue reactivity Ref object. However, those that are not wrapped by a Ref do not have consistent values across different contexts/scopes. Here's example code that represents what I'm trying to do:

Store.ts:

```
export interface Store {
  container: Container | undefined;
  reactiveProperty: Ref<Property | undefined>;
  getContainer: () => Container | undefined;
  getProperty: () => Property | undefined;
}

function useStore(): Store {
  let container: Container | undefined = undefined;
  const reactiveProperty: Ref<Property | undefined> = ref();
  

  function getContainer() {
    return container;
  }

  function getProperty() {
    return property.value;
  }

  return {
    container,
    reactiveProperty,
    getContainer,
    getProperty
  };
}

const store = useStore();
export {store};
```

App.ts:

```
import {store} from '@/store';

let {container, reactiveProperty, getContainer, getProperty} = store;

onMounted(() => {
  container = new Container();
  reactiveProperty.value = new Property('foo');
  const savedContainer = getContainer(); //savedContainer is undefined
  const savedProperty = getProperty(); //savedProperty has the correct value
});
```

I've also tried wrapping all member accesses into getters and setters, as well as directly accessing the properties using `store.container`. The latter works when used in different parts of the app, but a call to `getContainer()` would still return undefined.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @Quentin Sort of. I figured it'd be something related to passing semantics in JS, but I haven't figured out yet how exactly I need to change my code to work properly.